# Need I setup the dll in the server

Tags: asp.net, mysql

I just use Mysql connecter .Net in my project. It works in my computer when i test. when i upload the project to my server, it says `The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid`.

Is that something wrong, actually the server never setup the Mysql connector in the server. So if the connecter is not setupped in server, i cannot use it in server?

So in all, if i did not setup it in server just upload my project with dll(Mysql.Data.dll), it cannot work?

Answer (score 0):

[1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysqldotnet/) adding reference of any dll in your project is only works for your local run.

[2] if you want to run same thing on server, then add your dll (Mysql.Data.dll) to server's .Net Framework library folder. And for this you need to contact to server's administrator. Give this dll to them, they will add this dll in .net framework library folder, for you.

Thanks, i hope this will help to you.

OR

[1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysqldotnet/) **add code files of this DLL to your project directly
from here [Link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysqldotnet/)**

[2] **so no dll reference required and no dll registeration on server is required.**

this will defiantly solve your problem of adding Mysql.Data.dll to your project with godaddy web server.

Comment: you know, i use godaddy, so that should that i cannot use Mysql.Data....is that the dll should register in OS. if i have only ftp access, i can never use it.

Comment: i just wonder why i can use dll like CKeditor, it is also dll but it did not need to assist from OS administrator.

Comment: if you have open source code for this dll, then you can add this "source code" files to your project directly and then upload code to your godaddy server.

Comment: in godaddy server you can not add dll as a reference to your project and also not register this dll to godaddy server registry file.